# Error running custom command in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I'm running Python 3.6.3 and I've been trying to add a custom command to `setup.py`.

As far as I can tell what I've done appears to match the various tutorials and examples I've seen on this topic but I just can't get it to work.

I've stripped `setup.py` to the minimum. Here it is:

```
import setuptools

class FooCommand(setuptools.Command):
    user_options = []

    """Custom build command."""

    def initialize_options(self):
        """Abstract method that is required to be overwritten"""

    def finalize_options(self):
        """Abstract method that is required to be overwritten"""

    def run(self):
        print("Running foo command...")

setuptools.setup(
    cmdClass={'foo': FooCommand}
)
```

When I run `python setup.py foo`

I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'cmdClass'
  warnings.warn(msg)
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally figured it out. There's a typo in `cmdClass`. It should be `cmdclass` - i.e. all lower case.

```
setuptools.setup(
    cmdClass={'foo': FooCommand}
)
```